# menú desplegable que funciona ejecutando el html desde el pc pero no a través del servidor

Tags: javascript, menu

Tengo un menú desplegable con javaScript que funciona perfectamente al ejecutar el html directamente desde el pc pero al subir el proyecto al servidor y acceder a traves de la url (tanto desde un pc como en movil) no reacciona.

alguna idea?

El menu está contenido en un div con position fixed para que actue como una barra fija, pensé en algun conflicto de posición pero al añadir un alert en la funcion veo que no llega a saltar osea que el problema a mi parecer es que nisiquiera llega la llamada a esa función.

Resumen, tengo una funcion que chuta en local pero a través de la web no.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra un [repro] del código en cuestión. Es difícil determinar qué sucede sin más detalles. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Sin más detalles es imposible saber a ciencia cierta qué está pasando, pero puestos a advinar es posible que el fichero JS no se esté cargando, con lo que el comportamiento del menú no se activa nunca. Comprueba en las *web tools* si tienes alguna petición de recursos con un estado 404

Comment: Gracias pablo, el problema era exactamente ese.
No cargaba por que en el enlace del recurso puse http en lugar de https, al faltarle el protocolo de seguridad  el servidor bloqueaba la llamada.

Comment: En esos casos te recomiendo que uses enlaces relativos siempre que puedas y en caso de que no puedas usarlos, puedes usar enlaces al mismo esquema si necesitas acceder a través del mismo protocolo. Por ejemplo, `//localhost/archivo.js` cargará `https://localhost/archivo.js` si la página está en HTTPS o bien `http://localhost/archivo.js` si está en HTTP. Ojo porque esto solo funciona con aquellas páginas que tienen alojados sus recursos en paralelo en ambos esquemas y, además, es preferible usar https siempre que puedas.

Comment: Se necesita más información, pero casi seguro hay una ruta absoluta en el src del script, por lo que carga local pero no en el servidor.